# Sender and From header domain mismatch causes malformed display in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook

We're using Mailgun to send promotional email messages, and we have a separate subdomain set up for that purpose (`mail.example.com`). This domain is also specified in the `Sender` header.
On the other hand, the address in the `From` header uses an `example.com` domain.

This works fine on the majority of major email providers, but Outlook has decided not to use the display name and address specified in the `From` header and replaces it with `news=example.com@mail.example.com <news=example.com@mail.example.com> on behalf of News <news@example.com>`. This looks... less than professional.

I understand it would raise suspicion if the domains were completely different, but in our case, one is a subdomain of the other.

Is this behavior described somewhere in the RFC, or is it just Microsoft's policy? Are there any workarounds, besides changing the `Sender` or `From` domains?

Answer (score 1):

The sender and from must match to prevent that problem.

I can't find the policy, but yes it's to tighted their protections against not wanted email.

You are not alone in that problem;

- [Removing 'on behalf of' when sending mail using MailGun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401673/removing-on-behalf-of-when-sending-mail-using-mailgun)
- [Why Do I See "On Behalf Of" in My Email?](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012491394-Why-Do-I-See-On-Behalf-Of-in-My-Email-)